# Vaadin/GWT: different behaviour with Dev Mode on and off

Tags: gwt, vaadin, gwt-super-dev-mode

I'm developing a Vaadin widget and I'm having problems with GWT's superDevMode. Yesterday I had a bug which did not show up when setting Dev Mode On (using the bookmark), but did when setting Dev Mode Off.

Today I have unwanted behaviour when setting Dev Mode On, while with Dev Mode Off the behaviour is as expected.

Does anyone have a clue what might be causing this? Maybe a compiler setting?

Comment: Please describe bug that you are facing. "Unwanted behaviour" does not say much.

Comment: I realize that. But I'm not sure I can call it a bug. The first one I had was that a height variable was calculated differently with Dev Mode off. Somehow this problem disappeared although I can't really trace why.

The problem I have now is that with Dev Mode off, a span element which is generated if some boolean is true does not appear (bug) while it does appear after setting Dev Mode on.

Before discussing specific code, I thought I'd ask about any general cause for these kinds of differences first since I've had about three of these quirks.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out the problem was that I forgot to recompile the WidgetSet in Eclipse before starting the server, so when loading the page (before setting Dev Mode on) the WidgetSet would not have the latest changes. When setting Dev Mode on, the WidgetSet would be recompiled and thus incorporate the latest changes.